# Properties of Equilateral Triangles in Circles

Tags: circles, triangles

If there is an equilateral triangle in a circle, would the midpoint of any of the 3 sides be half the radius?

e.g if the radius was 6 and at the midpoint of the triangle (call it B) would center to B be 3 and then B to circle be 3 as well?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please show us what you have tried so far 
and where you are stuck, i.e edit your post with this information
, so that someone can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. If you're familiar with construction using compass and straight edge, one of the easiest ways to construct an equilateral triangle is to draw two circles where each circle's centre lies on the other circle's edge. Drawing a line between the two intersection points and then from each intersection point to the point on one circle farthest from the other creates an equilateral triangle. You can see from this construction that the side of the equilateral triangle between intersection points is equidistant from each centre, proving that the side is halfway between the circle's centre and its edge.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If the inner triangle is equilateral, then the angle $y = 60^o$, and since the OBA is a right triangle, the angle $x = 30^o$

If "B to the circle" in the question is $|BA|$, then it is $3\sqrt{3}$, (not 3).

If "B to the center" in the question is $|BO|$, then it is 3.

Comment: This is, I think, incorrect, with all due respect.

Comment: @Joanpemo it had to be $3\sqrt{3}$, I have fixed it.

Comment: Thank you. I still think it is wrong. The claim, I think, is true. Read my proof (unless, of course, my proof has a flaw)

Comment: @Joanpemo the results are the same with your proof. The triangle is 30-60-90 triangle, and if the radius is 6, the other length of the vertices are 3 and $3\sqrt{3}$

Comment: And thus the claim is right, isn't it? Perhaps it is just that the asker's notation is very confusing and your answer seems to try to disprove the claim.

Comment: @Joanpemo the question says "and then B to circle be 3 as well?" which is not true, because the length he asks "B to circle" is the length of MC in your proof, and it is not 3.

Comment: @hardmath I am sorry, but I did not get what you mean. Could you clarify your point?

Comment: @hardmath you are right. I could add a geometric explanation or a drawing at least. I will delete my answer.

Comment: I don't ask you to do that, but only help me understand it with a few more words.  Of course a picture will not hurt.

Comment: @hardmath ok, I added a drawing, hope this helps. thanks for comments.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  However I suspect the OP was asking about the distance from midpoint $B$ to the *nearest point* on the circle (not the corner $A$ of the triangle).

Comment: @hardmath It could be. However I thought the other way. I hope the owner of the question will clarify this.

Comment: I think Corbah is right: it could be understood either way as the question isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Draw a picture : From the circle's center draw a radius to a vertex and a line to the midpoint of a side with that vertex at one extreme. Then you get a $\;30-60-90\;$ little triangle and thus the line from center to the midpoint is opposite to the angle of $\;30^\circ\;$ and is thus half the hypotenuse which is the radius.

A drawing could probably help a lot here, but unfortunately I've no idea how to do that here.

Ok, now I've learned! in the drawing below, $\;AM\;$ is a median to $\;BC\;$ in circle $\;O\;$ . Observe that triangle $\;\Delta OMC\;$ is $\;30-60-90\;$ , and $\;OM\;$ is opposite to angle $\;30^\circ\;$ , thus

$$|OM|=\frac{|OC|}2$$

[image]

Answer (score -1):

No. In that case, the angle of triangle must be $45^{\circ}$ because is isosceles.

Comment: Your answer is to short to follow.  The Question asks about an equilateral triangle, and your Answer concerns an isosceles (right?) triangle.   The connection is unclear, perhaps something based on comparison of side lengths and radius?

Comment: I thin this is wrong, with all due respect.